# How does async work in Express?

Tags: node.js, express, asynchronous

I found the following on the [ExpressJS guide](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/database-integration.html#mysql):

```
var mysql      = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : 'localhost',
  user     : 'dbuser',
  password : 's3kreee7'
});

connection.connect();

connection.query('SELECT 1 + 1 AS solution', function(err, rows, fields) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log('The solution is: ', rows[0].solution);
});

connection.end();
```

Isn't this supposed to be bad practice? The way I see it, it is possible for the connection to end before the query can be executed. Wouldn't that give an error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated [here](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#introduction) :

- Every method you invoke on a connection is queued and executed in sequence.
- Closing the connection is done using end() which makes sure all remaining queries are executed before sending a quit packet to the mysql server.

So even though the call to the `end()` method can be made before the query has completed, it won't actually be executed until the query has finished executing.

This has to do more with the `mysql` package than NodeJS itself.

Comment: Sure, but the call back will not have happend  -- that will happen after `end` -- so I would think this is bad code

Comment: It doesn't matter if the callback hasn't happened, you're calling `end()` when you're done with SQL operations, it won't prevent your previous queries from running. Wether or not you consider this bad code is up to you, but it won't "give an error" as asked in the question.

Comment: So what happens if the call back code creates a new query?

Comment: It does not in this case, so it will not throw an error. There are other ways of doing this highlighted in the documentation of the package. I find it unfair to downvote my answer simply because you don't like the way of doing things of the `mysqljs/mysql` package. I simply explained why his code *works*. I'm not saying it's the best or only way to do things.

Comment: The OPs question was about whther the style was bad practice.   Two comments (1) does it work if you submit a new query in the callback -- the answer to that would suggest how good a practice e it is, and (2) you post does not have a single down vote

Answer (score 0):

Your question *How does async work in Express?* and *Isn't this supposed to be bad practice?*  can be answered in many ways, but for clarity I would like to explain that **It depends !!!!**

It **generally** is very bad practice, **assuming** you don't know the actual implementation.

If the the implementation is really simple, where it does exactly what you ask -- i.e. closes or ends the connection when `end` is executed then it could lead to rather ugly race conditions where it may or may not work depending on the load of the machines.

However, a clever implementation that does reference counting -- that is the `end` does not actually close the connection but just sets a flag to say -- "*when last callback is done then close*" -- then it may work.

If the mysql connector it implemented using reference counting then this may well work fine -- but that is not the same as saying that it is good practice for everything you find as a plugin.